# 2 Factor Authentication in Web Api project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to implement 2 Factor Authentication in a Web Api project. But it seems that 2FA cannot be implemented in Web Api where AccountController inherits ApiController. Is it possible to implement 2FA in Web Api solution and not MVC?

Answer (score 2):

The question is very broad, however to answer your questions yes it is possible.

See here - http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/15/two-factor-authentication-asp-net-web-api-angularjs-google-authenticator/

Code from link that is responsible for generating verification code-

```
public static class TimeSensitivePassCode
{
    public static string GeneratePresharedKey()
    {
        byte[] key = new byte[10]; // 80 bits
        using (var rngProvider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            rngProvider.GetBytes(key);
        }

        return key.ToBase32String();
    }

    public static IList<string> GetListOfOTPs(string base32EncodedSecret)
    {
        DateTime epochStart = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

        long counter = (long)Math.Floor((DateTime.UtcNow - epochStart).TotalSeconds / 30);
        var otps = new List<string>();

        otps.Add(GetHotp(base32EncodedSecret, counter - 1)); // previous OTP
        otps.Add(GetHotp(base32EncodedSecret, counter)); // current OTP
        otps.Add(GetHotp(base32EncodedSecret, counter + 1)); // next OTP

        return otps;
    }

    private static string GetHotp(string base32EncodedSecret, long counter)
    {
        byte[] message = BitConverter.GetBytes(counter).Reverse().ToArray(); //Intel machine (little endian) 
        byte[] secret = base32EncodedSecret.ToByteArray();

        HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1(secret, true);

        byte[] hash = hmac.ComputeHash(message);
        int offset = hash[hash.Length - 1] & 0xf;
        int truncatedHash = ((hash[offset] & 0x7f) << 24) |
        ((hash[offset + 1] & 0xff) << 16) |
        ((hash[offset + 2] & 0xff) << 8) |
        (hash[offset + 3] & 0xff);

        int hotp = truncatedHash % 1000000; 
        return hotp.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0');
    }
}

public static class StringHelper
{
    private static string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567";

    public static string ToBase32String(this byte[] secret)
    {
        var bits = secret.Select(b => Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')).Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);

        return Enumerable.Range(0, bits.Length / 5).Select(i => alphabet.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(bits.Substring(i * 5, 5), 2), 1)).Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
    }

    public static byte[] ToByteArray(this string secret)
    {
        var bits = secret.ToUpper().ToCharArray().Select(c => Convert.ToString(alphabet.IndexOf(c), 2).PadLeft(5, '0')).Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);

        return Enumerable.Range(0, bits.Length / 8).Select(i => Convert.ToByte(bits.Substring(i * 8, 8), 2)).ToArray();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am wondering how in MVC generating verification code and authenticating user, the same thing like MVC can be archived in Web API without 3rd party generating verification code.

Comment: Just thought of adding more to my previous comment. Is it possible to send 2FA verification code using Web API.

Comment: Added the piece of code responsible for generating verification code